# Calcular o numero de horas entre duas horas e transformar em float

Tags: php, codeigniter, time, float

Necessitava de criar uma funcção que recebesse duas horas no formato (00:00:00), calcula-se o número de horas entre elas, e me converte-se para float.

No entanto o float seria deste gênero:

```
Resultado: 2 horas e 30 min -> 2,30
Resultado: 3 horas e 45 min -> 3,45
Resultado: 3 horas e 1 min -> 3,01
resultado: 3 horas e 59 min -> 3,59
```

Comment: E quantos aos segundos, como ficaria a formatação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe um problema de conceito, no caso 2 horas e 30 minutos deveria em ponto flutuante ser representado como 2,50 isso porque 1 hora que no caso é avaliado como 1.0 em ponto flutuante  são 60 minutos, partindo desse princípio 30 minutos deveria equivaler 0.5 sendo assim 2 horas e 30 minutos ==> 2,50 e não 2,30 como apontado acima!

usando-se regra de 3 você converte baseando-se em minutos (se a precisão for em minutos) basta converter o período em minutos.

02:30 (duas horas e trinta minutos) ==> 150 minutos

na regra de 3

a relação 1 para 60, ou seja 1 em ponto flutuante equivale a sessenta minutos
e obter o valor em ponto flutuante equivalente ao que se quer converter (150 minutos) considerando-se a proporção estabelecida, obtendo-se assim a expressão abaixo

```
60X = 150*1 ==> X = 150/60 ==> X = 2,50
```

Comment: Obrigado, estava mesmo a pensar mal :D